# How to print an array of 5 values 1D as columns?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of integer values that is of one dimension.I need to print it as columns.
Although I can print the values as columns but it pritns more than 5 values. The ideal output would be like this:

```
1 1 1
1 1
```

How would i do this?
For example, my try is this:

```
int main(){

int array[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};

  cout<<"array printed in the form of columns: "<<endl;

   for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){

         cout<<setw(3)<< array[i]<<endl<<setw(3)<<array[i];
      }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you printing `array[i]` twice in the loop?

Comment: I put it two times to print two columns...

Comment: See how the code block is formatted. Do the same thing for your expected output. Do you want the output in 2 *rows* by any chance?

Comment: the output should be like 3 1s in the first line, with width 3 and 2 1s(the remaining) on the second line with width of 3 again.

Comment: I edited the question. Is that how you want the output to appear?

Comment: Yes this is it.Sorry I didnt knew how to put it that way, it didnt show as i typed(which is wrong)

Comment: See my edits. You can use 3 backticks, i.e. ``` to format code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write 2 loops:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
         cout << setw(3) << array[i];   // first row
}

cout << endl;       // next row

for ( int i = 3; i < 5; ++i ) {
         cout << setw(3) << array[i];   // second row 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If as columns, then it the

```
 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      cout << a[i] << endl;
 }
```

would be sufficient.

But you probably want the row-representation. (1 1 1 1 1, right?). Then

```
 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      cout << a[i] << " ";
 }
```

would suffice. Or, you can use a pointer

```
int * p_array = array;
```

and then, inside the loop

```
cout << *(p_array + i) << " ";
```

EDIT:

That was for your unedited question :-) For the new output -> you can follow the answer of the **Cigien**

Comment: Seems unnecessary to use pointers for this. It just makes the code harder to read, and write.

Comment: @cigien, it is yet another way to do the task :) It does not make it wrong, but is a mere introduction to pointers at this early stage.

Comment: No it's not wrong, but it adds complexity without any benefits, as far as I can tell.

Comment: With that I can agree :-)

Comment: Yes thank you for all the answers...I still dont know how to use pointers, I wanna take it step by step. I think you guys get it because this is pretty basic stuff...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could simply insert an end line after each 3(or any number of columns that you want) element printed.

Here is an exemple with a longer array :

```
int main()
{

    int colNum = 3;

    int array[7] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int len = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));

    cout<<"array printed in the form of columns: " << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < len ; i++ )
    {

        cout << array[i];
        if ((i+1)%colNum==0) cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't the condition be simply `if (i == 2)`?

Comment: Yes indeed, I misinterpreted the post and thought he might have some cases where he would have more than 5 elements and would still want 3 columns.

Comment: Aah, I see. That's reasonable. You could put up a solution demonstrating that. Make sure not to hardcode the `5` though :)

Comment: Much nicer. Good job :)